# why fatal error like using $this when not in object content?

Tags: php

I have a problem with the following code. When I use `$this` when not in object content.

**dashboardController.php**

```
<?php
   class dashboardController extends BaseController{
     public function index($name=''){
        $this->view->loadView('dashboard/index');
    }

}
```

**baseController.php**

```
<?php
class BaseController{
    public function loadView($viewName){
      $this->view = new View($viewName);
    }
}
```

**view.php**

```
<?php 
  class View{
    public function __construct($viewName);{  echo " i am form view to render 
    }
}
```

I am getting the error using `$this` when not in object content but in another folder the login went success without.

Comment: Have you called the method statically without instantiating the object first? e.g `dashboardController::index()`?

Comment: no i have not called the method like that but whenever i called the parent constructor like parent::__constructor it also gives me error and when i called the next method of the same class like parent::ss(); it went good

Comment: while calling the method of the parent class shall we have to instantiate the object i dont think so cant we direclty call the parent calss method from the child class

Comment: You can call the parent method by using `$this` providing you aren't overriding the method in the child class. `$this->ss();` will call the parent `ss()` if your child class doesn't have it's own `ss()` method. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

Comment: does my code above among three classes wrong or is it correct?

Comment: The class `View` is invalid as the echo isn't closed and you're trying to `loadView` on the `View` class, I'll add an answer.

Comment: isnt my code above is correct?

Comment: ok i am waiting for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**dashboardController**

```
<?php

class dashboardController extends BaseController
{
    public function index($name = '')
    {
        // Call loadView(), because this controller doesn't have a method
        // called loadView() it'll fall back to loadView() in the BaseController 
        $this->loadView('dashboard/index');

        // Get the viewName from the view, will be 'dashboard/index'
        echo $this->view->getViewName();
    }
}
```

**BaseController**

```
<?php

class BaseController
{
    // The view, protected so it can be accessed by children via $this->view
    protected $view; 

    // Load a view, protected so it can only be accessed by children 
    // or within this controller
    protected function loadView($viewName)
    {
        // Create a new view instance
        $this->view = new View($viewName);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<?php 

class View
{
    // The loaded view, private so it can't be changed by an external class
    private $viewName;

    public function __construct($viewName)
    {  
        $this->viewName = $viewName;
    }

    // Retrieve the view name, public so anything can access it
    public function getViewName()
    {
        return $this->viewName;
    }
}
```

Comment: sir i want to show you some routing code of mine will you check it and correct it if mistake and give me some idea how to utilize can you give me your email id

Comment: Add it to your original question and I’ll update the answer when I get a chance, I assume you’re calling the controller statically